# leaflet multiple layers control

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am using leaflet to build a layer control with three layers all of them shouldn't be on the map simultaneously. A layer should only appear on the map with a click. the code below doesn't work

```
   var attractionnyc = L.layerGroup();
   var museumsnyc = L.layerGroup();
   var hotelsnyc = L.layerGroup();

    L.control.layers ({}, {
         'Attraction': attractionnyc,
    },  {
        collapsed: False,
    }).addTo(map);

      L.control.layers ({}, {
         'Museum': museumsnyc,
    },  {
        collapsed: False,
    }).addTo(map);

        L.control.layers ({}, {
         'Hotels': hotelsnyc,
    },  {
        collapsed: False,
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `.addTo(map)` you are adding it to the map. You need to do some sort of click event, you can set your layer as a variable like attraction and do something like `attraction.addEventListener("click", function(){attraction.addTo(map)});`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://github.com/ismyrnow/leaflet-groupedlayercontrol The Advanced demo has two layers on radio buttons allowing only one on at a time.